Dropbox .NET SDKのCopyV2Asyncメソッドでルートの異なるチームフォルダー間でファイルをコピーしたい
DropboxのAPI(.NET SDK)のCopyV2Asyncメソッドを利用してルートの異なる（ネームスペースが異なる）チームフォルダー間でファイルをコピーしたいと思っていますが、可能でしょうか？
そもそもチームフォルダーに対してコピーを含む様々な操作を行う為には、DropboxClient.WithPathRootに操作対象チームフォルダーのネームスペースIDを指定する必要があることは理解していますが、ルートの異なる移動やコピー操作のように複数のネームスペースを扱う場合、ネームスペースIDを1つしかセットできない為、コピー元またはコピー先を認識できずエラーとなってしまいます。
